Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "mysqli" not found
Buenas estoy intentando hacer una pequeña web pero en el login es donde tengo el error pero no consigo solucionarlo al introducir el usuario y contraseña me da el siguiente error:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "mysqli" not found in C:\Apache24\htdocs\login.php:9 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\Apache24\htdocs\login.php on line 9
el codigo php es el siguiente:
    // Conexión a la base de datos
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "xxxxxxxxxx";
    $database = "resi"; // Nombre de tu base de datos
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

    // Verificar la conexión
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Error de conexión: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    // Obtener nombre de usuario y contraseña del formulario
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // Consulta SQL para verificar las credenciales del usuario
    $sql = "SELECT rol_id FROM Usuarios WHERE nombre_usuario='$username' AND contraseña='$password'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

la linea 9 es donde falla, la contraseña e puesto xxxxx en el post obviamente es otra
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
la version de php que uso es 8.3.4 y la version de mysql 8.1
en el documento php.ini la parte de extensión las tengo asi y se encuentra en la hubicacion C:\php que imagino que el documento php.ini que debo modificar es ese.
;extension=ffi
;extension=ftp
;extension=fileinfo
;extension=gd
;extension=gettext
;extension=gmp
;extension=intl
;extension=imap
;extension=mbstring
;extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=oci8_19  ; Use with Oracle Database 19 Instant Client
;extension=odbc
;extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
;extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql
;extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop```


y el phpinfo funciona de maravilla por el cual imagino que apache se entiende perfectamente con php






use PDO ... mejor

Como estás usando Apache nativo, pudiera ser que está usando fast-cgi y por eso no ha tomado los cambios. Reinicia el servidor de Apache cada vez que modifiques algo en php.ini para que refleje los cambios. Verifica también en un <?php phpinfo();?> si se está cargando realmente el módulo de mysqli.

entiendo, lo voy a mirar muchas gracias, un saludo!
